# GCP LB monitor healthy nodes count

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-load-balancer

Google cloud load balancer monitoring dashboard provides number of healthy nodes:
[image]

Is it any metric / MQL which can be used to create an alert if one node considered as down?

Comment: As best practice here on Stack Overflow, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Another option is to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is useful for you. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct metric for the Load Balancer's backends, but what you can do is to create a [Monitoring group](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/groups) containing them, and then set up an [Uptime check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/introduction) for monitoring and alerting; you can follow these steps to accomplish that:

1. Tag all the backend instances:

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags <instance_name> --tags=lb-backend --zone <instance_zone>
```

2. Create the monitoring group using `Resource Type = gce_instance` AND the tag as discriminators:
   [image]
3. Create the Uptime check and alerting policy for that group:
   [image]